# Preserve positioning of HTML page when window minimized

Tags: html, css, window, position, minimized

I have a problem with my page.
Whenever I minimize the window the positioning of all the elements goes off and things get distorted.

Comment: Wow, that's really strange. What browser is this?

Comment: Please show a live example or some code.

Comment: Its probably because you have used a mixture of pixels and percentages. Try making it one or the other

Answer (score 4):

If the elements go off their position when you make your browser window too small, use the [CSS min-width property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_min-width.asp). It makes the web browser show the scroll bar instead of trying to shrink the web page.

Like this:

```
body {
    min-width: 700px;
}
```

Comment: How is minimizing the window going to affect rendering whether `min-width` is there or not?

Comment: i am not an expert. i dono why. but the content in the body of the page got misaligned when i minimized thw window. so i set min-width for the <body> and then its solved. when width of the minimized window is less than min-width set by me it gives a horizontal scroll

Comment: hey guys one problem this doesnt work for IE . need help!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: http://css.flepstudio.org/en/css-tips/min-width-ie6.html